# How to handle form data by calling a PHP function in jQuery Mobile using Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I am currently working no a 6-page **form** using jQuery Mobile and are having some problems handling my **form** results. What I want to do is get all data sent to a .php script so the .php script can print and/or save to my database.

I've often had problems with everchanging variable names as they seem like a pain to manipulate. Perhaps someone know a *better way to do this* as I am pretty new to jQuery and Ajax. I have attempted to explain how my thought process is underneath.

Has anyone done anything similar that can show me in the right direction? I am pretty much in the dark here as what to google. Perhaps a link to something relevant? I would post any code if I had some, but I haven't really found anything useful to try yet. My form is generated through a .php function however, but saving the results is sort of the opposite of that.

Demands:
 
 - No page reload
 - Having the possibility to use mysql_real_escape_string before saving to db
 - Submit method: POST
 - Target db table needs question_id, option_id, user_id, date and other (for possible comments)

HTML pseudo code (generated by .PHP) - Without spans/fieldsets/labels etc

```
     <form action="<!-- What to put here?-->" method="POST" id="questions">
     <input type="radio" name="1[]" value="1"/>
     <input type="radio" name="1[]" value="2"/>
     <input type="radio" name="1[]" value="3"/>

     <input type="checkbox" name="2[]" value="1"/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="2[]" value="2"/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="2[]" value="3"/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="2[]" value="4"/>
     <textarea name="2[]" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
     <!-- ... -->
     <a type="submit" href="#results" onclick="formSubmit()" data-role="button">Submit</a>
     </form>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
     function formSubmit()
     {
     document.getElementById("questions").submit();
     }
```

Desired output in .php:
$answers = ("questionid" => "answerid", "questionid" => "answerid", "questionid => "answertext") for all **checked** checkboxes/radiobuttons and textfields != "".

Edit:
I've found out I probably need an id for my form so it shall hereby be named as *questions*.

The best way to do it would perhaps be by calling the .php script with an *onclick* on the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need help doing a simple AJAX submission but maybe there's some hidden question in here I've missed but I'll answer anyway.

So what you want is to look at this tutorial here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

You set your URL to AJAX submit to a handler PHP script which will then do what you want with the data and return a status, success/failed etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: **"You might notice that I have included a div with id contact_form that wraps around the entire form. Be sure to not miss that div in your own form as we will be needing this wrapper div later on."**
This will be problematic due to the fact that I have a 6-page form, the div's come and go but my form keeps going until the last page. I tried wrapping the whole page in another div but that stopped my navigation from working as I need the href="#page1" and so on to navigate through the sites. Any possible solutions around this? Thanks for the answer though, it still helps!

Comment: Why don't you submit each page as its own form and store the data in the $_SESSION as you go through each step. That way you can run server side validation too. You'd have different AJAX requests on each form and on success show the next step. I get why you have one form so all your POST data is kept there, but I'd utilise the session here.

Comment: Ah, very good idea! I was considering going to make 6 separate forms with 6 different submit buttons who saved the data in 6 separate functions, which would have been weak. Thing is I wasn't too sure on how to work sessions in anything other than .php so I was saving that for the next step, but I will change my focus now. Is it better to work with cookies or try to transfer the .php session from the login over to jQuery with a session handover (or whatever it's called)?

Comment: Well you mentioned you were using PHP so I meant the session in PHP. I was thinking you could have one form, with 6 buttons. The buttons call 6 different AJAX calls, so each step gets saved to the session as it is done, the onSuccess could have a call to hide the completed step and show the next one. 

A basic example being --

`<form id="myform">
<div id="step1">
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
<input type="button" onClick="yourCall('step1');" />
</div>
<div id="step2" style="display: none;">--inputs--</div>
</form>`

Comment: You can try and work smart and use one handler that based on a passed parameter does something different. I can't do the work for you though :) but hopefully it gives you some direction with that tutorial?